# Apply a function to multiple files to load data into a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a number of JSON files with a messy structure. I want to parse these into a PySpark DataFrame. I wrote a parsing function and would like to apply this to each file in a directory and feed those into my DataFrame.

I am completely new to PySpark so any help is appreciated. I had hoped I could do something to the effect of:

```py
from my_parsers import parser

data_files = [...] # Is there a PySpark way to iterate through files in a directory?

my_data = map(parser, data_files) # How do I collect each of these into the same object
```

The data that needs parsing is essentially a list of lists of rows
e.g.

```json
{"data": [["row 1 data"], ["row 2 data"], ...]}
```

Appreciate any help here - as I said I'm a total PySpark noob

Comment: Is the json structure same in all the files?

Comment: @DrashtiDobariya yes all files. Currently I am parsing them all into a list, then loading that list into a dataframe. This works, but I don't know how well it will scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the files have the same json structure, then you simply need to use the `spark.read.json` function.

Function spark.read.json accepts a list of files as a parameter.

```
spark.read.json(List_all_json file)
```

This will read all the files in the list and return a single data frame for all the information in the files.

For more information, read [this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-read-json-file-into-dataframe/)